# Sell digital content in ios device ?

Tags: ios

I'm working on an app for iOS. We'd like to sell digital content (some 100 books). The user will choose the book, pay for it and download it to mobile phone. So... How to make this procedure of payment, I really don't understand What I have to do? shall i go with in app purchase ?

Comment: Yes you should implement that using in-app purchases. Apple provides Storekit framework for that. If you find that complicated you can use other libraries of storekit such as https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit this :)

Comment: thanks but using in-app purchase i am facing a problem . All by books having different pricing like 40$,45$ and 50$ so on. But in-app purchase i have to choose some price from the price tire and from that price apple will cut 30 % . All these problems lead me to think about some third party gateway for purchase . Will Apple accept ?

Comment: Let someone else answer for that :) I need that answer too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are selling digital content on an iOS device then you have to use In App Purchase and Apple will take 30%. There is no choice about this.

An alternative is to sell content externally from the app and just use the app to download the content. For example, Amazon's Kindle App. You can't buy books from the app, you don't even have a link to buy books from the app. You can buy books from Amazon's website and download and view them in the Kindle app.

The relevant point is that if you are *selling* content through the app, you can't avoid IAP.

Comment: Thanks a lot . I got your point. But if i use in-app purchase then do i have dynamic pricing option . Means for in-app purchase i have to set some price tire from apple predefined price tire . But i want to set some price by own requirement like 45$ or 47$ . Is it possible ?